# How to avoid bundler files created under tmp folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

How to avoid bundler files created under tmp folder.

```
bundler20141117-10895-1r5qxu8  bundler20141211-10435-1yc6w27  
bundler20141117-29086-1wm3dbj  bundler20141211-15912-111zy8e  
bundler20141118-1626-1e8thb8   bundler20141211-18146-pwej9k
bundler20141118-21600-1bmpuhf
```